# using pointers to select numbers within a long unsigned variable

Tags: c++

I am required to add two select only two numbers from a Variable ie 0X11223344 and I want my pointers to pick 22 in the middle of the array. how do I go about it

Comment: `(0X11223344 >> 16) % 256`

Comment: You `memcpy` the unsigned long into a `unsigned char buffer[sizeof(unsigned long)]` and then iterate over `buffer` until you find a match with `unsigned char match = 0x22;` (or whatever matching value you choose), or exceed the size of the buffer in which case there was no match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shift and modulo operations to get the value

```
int main(){
   return (0X11223344 >> 16) % 256;
}
```

The program returns 34 == 0x22

A right shift of 4 removes 1 digit. A right shift of 16 removes 4 digits. A modulo of 16 removes all but one digits. A modulo of 16*16= 256 removes all but 2 digits.

You can also get the value with pointer operations:

```
int main() {
    int endianness = 2;
    int a = 0x11223344;
    char *b = ((char *) &a) + endianness;
    return *b;
}
```

The value of `endianess` is implementation defined. On a system with little endiannes it's 2

```
|01 02 03 04|  memory address
-------------
|44 33 22 11| 4 byte int with address 01 and value 0x11223344
|  |  |22|  | 1 byte char with address 03 and value 0x22
```

and on a system with big endianness it's 1

```
|01 02 03 04|  memory address
-------------
|11 22 33 44| 4 byte int with address 01 and value 0x11223344
|  |22|  |  | 1 byte char with address 02 and value 0x22
```

Comment: but can you use pointers to select the specific bytes in memory from that number?

Comment: @AnthonyBwembya I think it's undefined or implementation defined but you could try `int a = 0x11223344; char *b = ((char *) &a) + 2;`

Comment: @ThomasSablik not undefined. But the byte endianness is indeed implementation defined.